# Colocar un dato de primero en un objeto clave-valor de php

Tags: php

No estoy muy acostumbrado a php y necesito colocar un clave-valor a un objeto. Tengo esto:

```
 {"5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer"}
```

Necesito colocar al principio esto:

```
"no_job":"Please select an option"
```

Es decir, al final tendria algo como esto:

```
{"no_job":"Please select an option", "5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer"}
```

Intente con:

```
 $job_list["no_job"] = "Please select an option";
 array_unshift($job_list, $job_list["no_job"]);
```

Sin embargo el dato es duplicado al final:

```
{"no_job":"Please select an option", "5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02":"asistent","5bd0c379f109b673c11c9502":"seller","5be0addcf109b64c847abd26":"coder","5be0b26af109b64c847abd2c":"teacher","5becab8cf109b676d935e289":"engineer", "no_job":"Please select an option"}
```

Que me recomiendan hacer?

Answer (score 0):

En la práctica no tiene sentido colocar en determinado orden las propiedades de un objeto json, pero si realmente lo necesitas de esa forma puedes probar con [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php), uniendo a la nueva propiedad el objeto inicial.

Ej:

```
$test = array(
    'a'=>5,
    'b'=>4
);
$test2 = array('x'=>6);
$test = array_merge($test2,$test);
echo json_encode($test);
```

donde el resultado será

```
{"x":6,"a":5,"b":4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas controlar el orden de los elementos, yo te recomendaría utilizar un array secuencial en vez de uno asociativo:

```
$arr = [
    ["5ba68024f109b61fe95ccd02", "asistent"],
    ...
];
array_unshift($arr, ["no_job", "Please select an option"]);
```

De esta manera, si lo serializas en PHP con JSON y lo deserializas con otro lenguage, siempre te va a mantener el orden de los elementos; mientras que un array asociativo podría ser leído como un diccionario en otro lenguaje, que podría no mantener el orden de los elementos.